# how can I debug more than one script in pyscripter?

Tags: python, ide, debugging, pyscripter

I installed portable python on my USB drive, and I really like pyscripter a lot. The thing is, after I start debugging a script, the IDE kind of freezes ( waiting for the code to reach a breakpoint ). This means I can't do anything with it ( I can't even save files ). It would be very useful to be able to debug more than one script at a time.

I even tried starting a new instance of the IDE, but it comes back to the one open. Is there something I can do to be able to debug more than one script at a given time ?

Comment: How do you debug with pyscripter? I press debug, and then I type, print variable   but then i just hear a error noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, use [Remote Interpreter and Debugger](http://pyscripter.googlepages.com/remotepythonengines) and PyScripter will become much more responsive. Even if something goes wrong, IDE will not crash - just reinitialize remote interpreter and resume working.